# Merge Arrays of JSON

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

So my objective is to merge json files obtain this format:

```
{
  "title": "NamesBook",
  "list": [
    {
      "name": "Ajay"
    },
    {
      "name": "Al"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have files that look like this format:

blahblah.json

```
{
  "title": "NamesBook",
  "list": [
    {
      "name": "Ajay"
    }
  ]
}
```

blueblue.json

```
{
  "title": "NamesBook",
  "list": [
    {
      "name": "Al"
    }
  ]
}
```

I can store the list array of all my names in a variable with the following:

```
x = jq -s '.[].list' *.json
```

And then I was planning on appending the variable to an empty array in a file I created, out.json, which looks like this:

```
{
  "type": "NamesBook",
  "list": []
}
```

However, when my script runs over the line

```
jq '.list[] += "$x"' out.json'
```

It brings up a jq error:

> Cannot iterate over null.

Even when I add a random element, the same error shows up. Tips on how I should proceed? Are there other tools in jq to help achieve merging arrays?

Answer (score 53):

Let me also provide just what the **title asks for**, because I'm sure a lot of people that stepped on this question look for something simpler.

Any of the following (added [math2001](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6164984/math2001) and [pmf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2158479/pmf) answers):

```sh
echo -e '["a","b"]\n["c","d"]' | jq -s 'add'
```

```sh
echo -e '["a","b"]\n["c","d"]' | jq -s 'flatten(1)'
```

```sh
echo -e '["a","b"]\n["c","d"]' | jq -s 'map(.[])'
```

```sh
echo -e '["a","b"]\n["c","d"]' | jq -s '[.[][]]'
```

```sh
echo -e '["a","b"]\n["c","d"]' | jq '.[]' | jq -s
```

results in:

> [
> "a",
> "b",
> "c",
> "d"
> ]

Note: Also any of the above can **apply** to **arrays of objects**.

Comment: Worked like a charm for merging arrays! Thanks!

Comment: arguably simpler is `jq -s 'flatten(1)'`

Comment: Or `jq -s 'map(.[])'` or even `jq -s '[.[][]]'` but `jq -s 'add'` is the simplest.

Answer (score 24):

You can merge your files with *add* (jq 1.3+):

```
jq -s '.[0].list=[.[].list|add]|.[0]' *.json
```

or *flatten* (jq 1.5+):

```
jq -s '.[0].list=([.[].list]|flatten)|.[0]' *.json
```

`[.[].list]` - creates an array of all "list" arrays

```
 [
  [
    {
      "name": "Ajay"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Al"
    }
  ]
]
```

`[.[].list]|flatten` - *flatten* it (or `.[].list|add` - *add* all the arrays together)

```
[
  {
    "name": "Ajay"
  },
  {
    "name": "Al"
  }
]
```

`.[0].list=([.[].list]|flatten)|.[0]` - replace the first "list" with the merged one, output it.

```
{
  "title": "NamesBook",
  "list": [
    {
      "name": "Ajay"
    },
    {
      "name": "Al"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 14):

Assuming every file will have the same `title` and you're simply combining the `list` contents, you could do this:

```
$ jq 'reduce inputs as $i (.; .list += $i.list)' blahblah.json blueblue.json
```

This just takes the first item and adds to its list, the list of all the other inputs.

---

Since it appears this question got hijacked to answer a different problem... might as well offer answers to that too...

Given a *stream* of arrays, to combine the contents to a single array, I would write it:

```
$ jq -n '[inputs[]]' input.json
$ jq '[.[],inputs[]]' input.json
```

I wouldn't use slurp (-s) if I don't need to. Performance difference may be negligible, but is an unnecessary step. Though with larger inputs, you wouldn't want to use it anyway.

In such cases, you'll want to stream it in and you could filter out the ends of the arrays (the single item arrays).

```
$ jq --stream -n '[inputs|select(length==2)[1]]' input.json
```

Answer (score 4):

The OP did not specify what should happen if there are objects for which .title is not "NamesBook".  If the intent is to select objects with .title equal to "NamesBook", one could write:

```
map(select(.title == "NamesBook"))
| {title: .[0].title, list: map( .list ) | add}
```

This assumes that jq is invoked with the -s option.

Incidentally, `add` is the way to go here: simple and fast.