# How do I combine lists that are outputs of workflows in Github Actions

Tags: github, github-actions

I have two workflows that output a list with uploaded file names, `["foo","bar"]` and `["xyz","abc"]`. In a third workflow I need to download all these files and merge their content. However, I am stuck how to create one list out of those two lists.

How can this be done?

Comment: You may use `jq`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011086/merge-arrays-of-json.

Comment: `echo -e '["foo","bar"]\n["xyz","abc"]' | jq -sc 'add'` should result in `["foo","bar","xyz","abc"]`.

Comment: thanks. I was hoping for something as an expression I can use in `${{ }}` instead of having to go through the shell.